# CSS Chrome - Div with 0px height (and top-bottom border) not possible

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with the chrome browser. When I make custom "hr" tag with a "div" and top and bottom border, there is a white 1px line between the borders ...
IE and Firefox do well.

```css
.nav_links_container_line {
    border-top: 1px solid #096ebd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="nav_links_container_line"></div>
```

I try different thing (overflow, height 0px) but with no success.
My Chrome Browser is up to date (Version 62.0.3202.94)

Thank you 
Simon

Comment: When I look at your code in Chrome and zoom in to 500%, it is fine. No gap between the lines.

Comment: Im using Chrome v62 and this code work fine. I have no gap between the lines too. Try refresh page or use incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a real `<hr/>`? With that, I don't have the rendering issue you encountered, and it actually makes more sense to use `hr` in its own role.

```css
.nav_links_container_line {
    border-top: 1px solid #096ebd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="nav_links_container_line"></div>
<hr class="nav_links_container_line"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is not a white space, you used light-grey color to bottom and both border top and bottom attached and it's illusion like there is white space. If you want shadow for bottom of your custom hr then you can use following css for it -

```
.nav_links_container_line {
border-top: 1px solid #096ebd;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #000;
```

}